# Переключатель (кнопка)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

Можно ли как то реализовать подобный переключатель с помощью каких то готовых решений jquery? Существуют ли такие? При переключении кнопки (переключателя), блоки справа должны выделяться соответствующим образом. Как можно такое реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держи. Вот вариант на [SASS](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/vzWdoW?editors=1100), там можно все детально и удобно настроить.

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.can-toggle {
  position: relative;
}
.can-toggle *, .can-toggle *:before, .can-toggle *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox][disabled] ~ label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox][disabled] ~ label .can-toggle__switch {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .can-toggle__switch:before {
  content: attr(data-unchecked);
  left: 0;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  content: attr(data-checked);
}
.can-toggle label {
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__label-text {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 32px;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__switch {
  position: relative;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__switch:before {
  content: attr(data-checked);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  content: attr(data-unchecked);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox][disabled] ~ label {
  color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch, .can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch {
  background-color: #777;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after, .can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  color: #5e5e5e;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:hover ~ label {
  color: #6a6a6a;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label:hover {
  color: #55bc49;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .can-toggle__switch {
  background-color: #70c767;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  color: #4fb743;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch, .can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch {
  background-color: #5fc054;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after, .can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  color: #47a43d;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__label-text {
  flex: 1;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__switch {
  transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
  background: #848484;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__switch:before {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
  color: #777;
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after, .can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  transform: translate3d(65px, 0, 0);
}
.can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after, .can-toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.can-toggle label {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__switch {
  height: 36px;
  flex: 0 0 134px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__switch:before {
  left: 67px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 36px;
  width: 67px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 65px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.can-toggle label .can-toggle__switch:hover:after {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox][disabled] ~ label {
  color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.5);
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch, .can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch {
  background-color: #444;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after, .can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  color: #2b2b2b;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:hover ~ label {
  color: #373737;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label:hover {
  color: #6b99e8;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .can-toggle__switch {
  background-color: #8eb1ed;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  color: #6293e7;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:checked:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch, .can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch {
  background-color: #78a2ea;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:checked:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after, .can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  color: #4c84e3;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 label .can-toggle__label-text {
  flex: 1;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 label .can-toggle__switch {
  transition: background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  background: #515151;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 label .can-toggle__switch:before {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  color: #444;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after, .can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  transform: translate3d(108px, 0, 0);
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:checked:focus ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after, .can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover ~ label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 label {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 label .can-toggle__switch {
  height: 45px;
  flex: 0 0 220px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 label .can-toggle__switch:before {
  left: 110px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 45px;
  width: 110px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 label .can-toggle__switch:after {
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 108px;
  line-height: 41px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.can-toggle.demo-rebrand-2 label .can-toggle__switch:hover:after {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="can-toggle demo-rebrand-2">
  <input id="e" type="checkbox">
  <label for="e">
    <div class="can-toggle__switch" data-checked="Indivudual" data-unchecked="Company"></div>
    <div class="can-toggle__label-text"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сильно выручил!